# Rejected edits for correcting spelling

Tags: support, rejected-edits

When I am on Stack Overflow, I sometimes notice misspelling, or grammatical errors. Of course we are all human and make mistakes, and this is why when I see them I fix them. The first two times I adjusted some spelling they were accepted, but the last two times were rejected because:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the
>   revision history to see what should have been changed

I found this very strange. Of course I agree that I didn't fix any critical stuff, but spelling can annoy a lot of helpful people and that's why I try to fix it. But if they keep getting rejected I lose motivation to help people this way. So should I just ignore misspelling, or is there something else I can do to improve it?

Comment: I had the same problem at least two times recently. Very discouraging. I will be thinking twice before trying to edit anything from now on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8306886) looks fine to me. This appears to be an isolated incident, and I'd not take it as a precedent.

Only one reviewer disagreed, they picked the *Reject and Edit* option which includes a veto vote from Community. The [edit they did make](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30619225/revisions) is in my opinion much worse than yours and missed major mistakes your edit corrected.

I've edited the post to correct these omissions. It appears the reviewer picked the wrong option by mistake:

> I did an improve edit and added a space for the new sentence after the "."  I assumed that improve edit took the current edit and just added more to it.  I didn't release that it removed the previous edits.      "Actwindow.How can"  are contacted now and both highlighted

and

> Then I clicked the wrong button I distinctly remember adding the space after that  .  in Actwindow.How

Comment: Thank you, but I had the same issue with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476748/getting-info-and-field-name-from-database-and-align-them-together-in-console-app That's why I started to think that it wasn't an isolated incident and I did something wrong.

Comment: @Kyra: You accidentally removed a `}` closing brace in your edit; Soner's edit preserves it. They also handled the code formatting a little differently. It happens, not everyone agrees on what makes a good edit. Again, I'd not worry too much about this.

Comment: Oh indeed I made a mistake there. Thank you for answering my questions.

Comment: no it is not an isolated incident. The same happened to me several times.

Comment: @AndrejAdamenko: you have only 2 rejected suggested edits on SO, and neither of those were correcting spelling errors. Both those rejections happened many years ago, why mention them now?

Comment: @Martijn i think there is a misunderstanding here. In the past few months i tried to do dome spelling edits, but i could not even submit them, because i changed too few characters. The changes were too small and the system did not allow me to submit them.

Comment: @AndrejAdamenko: then you misunderstood the context of my answer entirely. No-one here is talking about the minimal character count requirements for suggested edits.